# NSArray or NSDictionary from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

In a method I need to read a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` from a `plist` file.

Here is my problem : How can I create a `NSArray` OR a `NSDictionary` from a `plist` file when I don't know if it's an array or dictionary in it ?

I know I can make :

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *myDico = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

But I don't know if filePath contains a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`. I would like something like :

```
id myObject = [... ...WithContentOfFile:filePath];
```

Can somebody help me and give me the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
id obj = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:nil];

if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    //cast obj to NSDictionary
}
else if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    //cast obj to NSArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use isKindOfClass method to detect which class is that.
You will have to load .plist file using:

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
id objectFromPlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization
   propertyListWithData:plistXML
   options:0
   format:&format
   errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

And you can check here:

```
if([objectFromPlist isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSArray* plistArray = (NSArray*) classFromPlist;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I get the classFromPlist object ?

Comment: Updated my answer with additional tips.

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly !
But the page [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nspropertylistserialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/propertyListWithData:options:format:error) said it will be deprecated soon.

Comment: Just use the new one than :) I updated the answer but not sure if still works - please check and let me know

Comment: Yep ! I use the method of @graver. Thank you both.

Comment: Yeah looks like he copy pasted it from my answer, but your welcome ;)